# Visual Studio Express 2012 with TFS Mapping wrongly

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I'm trying to map a folder from TFS, and it fouls it up every time I re-try doing it.
My structure on server is:

```
$/
--tool
----ASK
------Project1
------Project2
------Project3
------etc
```

I map to a local folder: C:\mytool and do a get. It correctly downloads all the folders in this structure:

```
C:/mytool
--tool
----ASK
------Project1
------Project2
------Project3
------etc
```

However, when I try to open ASK.sln (located in C:/mytool/tool folder) It fails when it tries to open projects.

Instead of opening

C:\mytool\tool\ASK\Project1

it complains that it can't find the project at

C:\mytool\tool\mytool\tool\Project1

and same for other projects, i.e.

C:\mytool\tool\mytool\tool\Project2

C:\mytool\tool\mytool\tool\Project3

Please help!
I've tried deleting everything, mapping C:\mytool to tool instead of '$/' and also to 'ASK' and every time it tries searching for projects in the wrong location.

Comment: I don't think this is a problem with TFS so much as with your solution file. I think when you save a solution file, it records the location of child projects. Would it be difficult to manually remove and add these projects to the solution?

Comment: That is a good idea, and I fully expected that to work, however when I tried to manually add the project though "add existing project", even though I clicked the existing project file at C:\mytool\tool\ASK\Project1 it complained that it couldn't find the project at C:\mytool\tool\ASK\tool\ASK\Project1. This has me really confused.

Comment: OK. Try cracking open the solution file in Notepad and changing the paths of the child projects in there.

Comment: Hmm no, I did this too. It didn't work.

Comment: A work colleague suggested moving the solution file from the ASK folder to the mytool folder, and that seemed to fix the problem

Comment: Go figure. Glad you got it sorted